# How to Flush WordPress Permalinks?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks, flush

1. I'm trying to do it in WP dashboard - no result.
2. There is no `rewrite_rules` string in my DB to flush.
3. But I have `woocommerce_queue_flush_rewrite_rules`. If I set it to YES, everything flushed fine. But after some time it become NO again and I have 404 errors.

Is there any way to automatize flushing process?..

Comment: Navigating to permalinks usually does a flush for you.  Note from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/#more-information, it's an expensive operation so best to only do when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Flush WordPress Permalinks with PHP**

> To flush WordPress permalinks, you need to copy and paste the code
>   below to your functions.php file:

```
Flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Comment: Flush_rewrite_rules(); even if rewrite_rules string do not exist in database?..